# country-state-city does not load at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm continuously having a problem with country-state-city in my react app. Code to pull it is as follows and the error is right below it. I haven't the slightest clue and I've been searching everywhere.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Box, TextField, Button, InputAdornment } from '@mui/material';
import csc from 'country-state-city';

export const Markups = () => {

    const [country, setCountry] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const getStates = async() => {
            try {
                let country_abbrv = 'US';
                let country = await csc.getCountryByCode(country_abbrv);
                let temp_states = await csc.getStatesOfCountry(country.isoCode);

                console.log(temp_states);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

        };
        getStates();
    })
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCountryByCode')
    at getStates (index.js:13:1)
    at index.js:22:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23142:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24920:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24885:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24872:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24860:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27032:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26978:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26929:1)
```

Comment: Their docs say that getCountryByCode is a function on the City object that they export

Comment: Ie `import { Country, State, City }  from 'country-state-city';` and  `City.getCountryByCode(countryCode)
 ` https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city#citygetcountrybycodecountrycode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their docs, that method does not exist on the default export. Instead it exports City, Country, etc.

```
import { Country, State, City }  from 'country-state-city';
City.getCountryByCode(countryCode);
```

Comment: face palming myself hard right now. thank you.

Comment: Btw, the way to read this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCountryByCode')` is: csc.getCountryByCode is evaluating to undefined. Then you're trying to call undefined(country_abbrv), which obviously isn't a function.

Comment: The first thing I would do when seeing this is log csc.getCountryByCode, which will be undefined, then log csc, which will show you which properties actually exist on it.